# SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode. in React app with Rails 5 API backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-api

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/superhighfives/a-top-shelf-web-stack-rails-5-api-activeadmin-create-react-app-de5481b7ec0b) on connecting a React app to a Rails 5 API. Everything went fine up to about halfway through with creation of the `Profile.dev`part, more precisely the creation of the rake tasks to manage running development and production locally.

The `Procfile.dev` looks like this

```
web: cd client && PORT=3000 npm start
api: PORT=3001 && bundle exec rails s
```

Following the instructions, I added the `start.rake` to `/lib/tasks` like so:

```
namespace :start do
  task :development do
    exec 'foreman start -f Procfile.dev'
  end

  desc 'Start production server'
  task :production do
    exec 'NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true npm run postinstall && foreman start'
  end
end

desc 'Start development server'
task :start => 'start:development'
```

I then added `foreman` to my gemfile in development group and ran `bundle install`as instructed.

```
group :development do
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  gem 'foreman', '~> 0.82.0'
end
```

The tutorial then says to run

```
bin/rake start
```

Which results in this error.

```
12:49:57 web.1  | const spawn = require('react-dev-utils/crossSpawn');
12:49:57 web.1  | ^^^^^
12:49:57 web.1  | SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
12:49:57 web.1  |     at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at startup (node.js:129:16)
12:49:57 web.1  |     at node.js:814:3
```

I looked around to find out what the problem might be but the only suggestions I've found so far is to upgrade Node.js, which I've already tried (v4.x and latest at time of posting v8.2.1).

Neither of these node upgrades fix the problem. Also as the error points to the `cross-spawn` package I thought it would be possible to change the version of this package in the `package.json`file. But [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) seems to abstract installed packages away in a way that makes this a less trivial task.

Any help getting past this error is much appreciated!